# Windows7 taskbar thumbnail without showing a window

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails, taskbar, aero, peek

Is it possible to "mark" my program as active in the windows7 taskbar without actually showing a window and even provide a thumbnail picture?
I worte a small program which displays the system battery as a deskband. Now in windows7 I'd like to display the battery in the thumbnail picture, and make the deskband optional.

Comment: Bear in mind that if aero is not enabled, that would leave you not showing the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to make your window permanently minimized. You can provide anything for the window's thumbnail.

Comment: Thx! Late but better then never ;)